# Exporting an image struct from native code to managed

Tags: wpf, mfc, c++-cli, interop, marshalling

I have a native codebase that creates an image every 50 ms. I want to use WPF to render this image into a WPF GUI view.

The image is an hbitmap constructed from a data structure of type boost::numeric::ublas::matrix. i.e. I start with a matrix of float values, then I create a HBITMAP, and then draw this HBITMAP using the device context of MFC. But now, I want to replace my MFC GUI with a WPF GUI, because it looks nicer. I plan to use C++/CLI to achieve the interop.

My question is as follows : How should I setup the transfer of my image across the interop boundary?

Should I transfer it over while it is still a structure of floats, or shall I transfer after I created the bitmap? I have heard marshaling is a big drain on efficiency, and so must be handled very carefully. Is there a type that is common to managed and native world, that can be used for this?

I am a complete newbie to interoping, any other related resources you share will be greatly appreciated.

Or, is there a way to completely avoid the transfer? - by drawing from native code into a WPF GUI view

My application is very performance sensitive, any alternative you suggest that achieves good performance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may create a WPF BitmapSource from an HBITMAP by [CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx). But do not forget to delete the bitmap handle afterwards, as explained e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens, does this approach prevent loss of efficiency due to marshaling?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly with "loss of efficiency due to marshaling", do you? You have an HBITMAP and create a BitmapSource from it, that's all.

Comment: You will have to try this anyway in order to find out if it is capable of creating 20 images per second. I guess it heavily depends on their sizes.

Comment: If the float values represent raw pixel data (or can easily transformed to do that), you might as well create a BitmapSource directly by one of its static [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616046(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Even directly from unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through the same options and found that - at least for .NET 4.5 - the [InteropBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.interopbitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the best way to go, as long as your image stays the same size (e.g. for something like video streaming).

In brief, you create a memory mapped file (either in using C++/CLI or C# with p/invoke), and use that as the source of pixel data. The `InteropBitmap` is created over that same memory mapped file, and you can use it as an `ImageSource` in WPF.

In my application, a background thread updates the MMF and invalidates the `InteropBitmap` and the WPF front end just binds to the image source as normal.